# jsoup Huge html download

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to download an HTML file, it is actually a table with about 6000 rows so I wrote this code

```
 Document _DOM=Jsoup.connect(_EXACT1_URL)
            .cookies(_COOCKIES)
            .timeout(70000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0")
            .get();
```

When I try to parse my Document(_DOM) and calculate the rows, all I get is 1127 rows
I try to write the document String in a file (page.html)and then parse, I get the same result, the file size is about (1.2 Mb) when I use my browser (Firefox) to download it the real size is (6 Mb)
I increased the JVM heap size memory like this

```
java -Xms32m -Xmx500 -jar myJarFile.jar, unfortunately, get the same result.
```

I will be very thankful for your help.

Comment: Jsoup formats the parsed Html, so the formating may differ from the one of the website. But what is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to set [maxBodySize(int)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.Request.html#maxBodySize%28int%29). The default size is 1mb.

For example:

```
Document _DOM = Jsoup.connect(_EXACT1_URL)
               .cookies(_COOCKIES)
               .timeout(70000)
               .maxBodySize(1024*1024*10) // Size in Bytes - 10 MB 
               .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0")
               .get();
```